# Writing to file from within a servlet(Deployer:Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-io

I am using the following code to write to a file from a servlet in Tomcat container. I don't worry if the file gets overwritten during each deploy.

```
BufferedWriter xml_out = null;
try {
    xml_out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator
                + "XML.xml"), "UTF8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    xml_out.write(xml);
    xml_out.flush();
    xml_out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, the file writing is not successful (it doesn't get written in the hard disk). Also, there isn't any exception that gets caught! Is there some security thing in Tomcat that is preventing the file from being written ?

Comment: what do you mean, "not successful"?

Comment: The file is not there on the hard disk after the servlet has finished its operation.

Comment: Are you catching any other exceptions anywhere? The WEB-INF folder is a protected area, so it it possible that this is write protected

Comment: I have also tried it in the WebContent folder, but no luck! I am wondering why the exception is not being caught. Seems like the file write if OK!! But I can't see the file!

Answer (score 2):

Your code has both "/" and the windows file separator at the start of the filename passed to `getRealPath()`, Java interprets slashes in filenames according to the current OS.

Not using the file separators might give a better result:

```
String filename = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/XML.xml");

log.debug("Using XML file: " + filename);

xml_out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename),"UTF8"));
```

Using a separate variable for the filename lets you log it so you can see unexpected results early in de development process.

Comment: This didn't work either! And I don't know how you used the log.debug method? Is log a standard class in java or I have to download some packages to use it?

Comment: @Bikash, you can use an instance of `java.util.logging.Logger` or use the log4j library for instance (or for the time being simply use `System.out`) you might write the file in a different location than what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, the file was written somewhere else. I checked for it, and edited the path name to get the correct destination. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011892/how-to-locate-the-path-of-the-current-project-in-java-eclipse) link helped me to understand where the file was in the hard disk.
Specifically for me, it put the file in the location that is returned by this line:

> System.getProperty("user.dir");

In my case the location was: *C:\Users\Myself\programming\eclipse for java*