# java can't mk dir and file at web-inf

Tags: java, file, web-inf

I want to create some files at WEB-INF/upload and
upload is a folder which contains some upload files.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
String dir = context.getRealPath("WEN-INF/upload");

File folder = new File(dir);
if(folder.exists()){
    //do something
}else{
    folder.mkdir();
}
```

it's a piece of simple code, and dir like this:

```
C:\Code\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MON\WEN-INF\upload
```

So I debug it in eclipse, and at the same time I get into

```
C:\Code\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MON\WEN-INF\
```

to watch whether the upload folder is been created.
There's no any exception, but the folder cannot be created, I don't know why,
Thanks.

Comment: do you have the required privileges to create a directory in WEN-INF?

Comment: I hope you calling `WEB-INF` as `WEN-INF` is just a typo!

Comment: Can you print out the absolute path for 'folder'? Also, it's generally a good idea to take care of the return value given by folder.mkdir(). It should be true if the folder got created

Comment: oh my god !!! Thanks adarshr. I find the reason so long. it seems that I need to have a break. Thanks.

Comment: @diligent No problem. It is a typo often committed by people who see and type. Touch-typists type the letters `B` and `N` using different index fingers, so they can never make *that* typo. :)

Comment: Are you trying to ultimately create a directory inside a packaged .war file? Changes cannot be made during runtime, any change requires regenerating and redeploying the entire WAR file.

Comment: You are aware that the servlet spec does not guarantee you can write to WEB-INF and you therefore have a subtle vendor dependency?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlet - save file to disk, but not sure what path to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342943/servlet-save-file-to-disk-but-not-sure-what-path-to-use)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen probably a better way to put it than my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir()` doesn't throw an exception; it returns `boolean` to indicate success or failure. You should always check its return value so your code can react accordingly.

As to why it's not being created, why are you using `"WEN-INF"` rather than `"WEB-INF"` ? Is this just a problem of a simple typo?