# How to Get a Project Path in Java..?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, path, project

I am working in a java plugin for Eclipse and i need get the project path from plugin 
Example

/home/user/workspace/project_name/

And i dont know how.

I tried this but it did not work

```
if (window != null)
        {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
            Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
            if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable)
            {
                IProject project = (IProject)((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
                IPath path = project.getFullPath();
               // System.out.println(path);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("zenity --warning --text '"+path+"';echo $?");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try look into this post [already reposonded here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011892/how-to-locate-the-path-of-the-current-project-in-java-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

`getFullPath()` returns the path of the project relative to the workspace root.

What you want is `getLocation()` which returns the full path of the project (or other resource) in the file system:

```
IPath path = project.getLocation();
```

Use the `IPath` `toOSString()` method to convert the path to a string in the correct format for the current OS:

```
String pathStr = path.toOSString();
```