# Gradle DSL method executable not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I use android studio.

I want to run a task ,for java jar file compilation so wanted to execute the "executable" as "java" in the gradle but it says

Gradle DSL method not found: 'executable()'
Possible causes:

The project 'logcatdemo' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.1.3 and sync project

The project 'logcatdemo' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

My build.gradle for module  is,

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        }
    }


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    task run (overwrite:true){
         executable 'java'
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

my app's build gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        android {

            compileSdkVersion 27
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.xxx.yyy.logcatdemo"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {

            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

        }


        build.finalizedBy("run")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [**`JavaExec`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html).

> Executes a Java application in a child process.

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {

}
```

Comment: I Need to include that , as the task is to execute java in a task, If run from the terminal where gradle is installed it works fine, but not in android studio

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

in the task add a parameter,

```
task run(type:JavaExec){

}
```

This cleared the error

Comment: How to get the pathname of the project, is there function for that and how to get the pathname of class files which the Android studio produces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011892/how-to-locate-the-path-of-the-current-project-in-java-eclipse

Comment: `File rootDataDir =getFilesDir();

Log.i("PROJECT", rootDataDir.toString());`

Comment: I need to get that In the gradle script itself